# Filtering with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Please, anyone knows how to make this filtering in pyspark?

I want to convert this code pandas to pyspark.
Thank for your help

`df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'B'] = np.NaN`|

Comment: You can use `.when()` https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent pyspark code using [`pyspark.sql.functions.when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) and [`pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise.html) is:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import numpy as np

df = df.withColumn("B", F.when(F.col("A") == 1, np.nan).otherwise(F.col("B")))
```